# Extract value from Polygon to Grid?

Tags: polygon, vector-grid, value-list

Can I extract value from a polygon that contains countries to Grid polygons that I have created?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can accomplish this with a spatial join which specifies your grid polygons as the target features and the country polygons as the join features using one to many join operation.

Comment: Can you specify this what you say to make  on ArcMap or Qgis?

Comment: ArcMap, but the same principles apply in QGIS.

Comment: Give me an exampe  with photo, please?